# Logical Operator || somehow doesn't give desired outcome

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, logical-operators

I have this variable that toggles if some things are enabled to be edited or not looking like this

```
enabled: !(parseInt("@Model.Status") === @((int)Status.Active) ||
!(parseInt("@Model.Status") === @((int)Status.Expired)) && '@Model.EditMode' === 'True'),
```

For some reason if this works for the ones with `active` status and not `expired` and if i turn it around and put `expired` first it works for `expired` but not `active` ones.... So i am wrong here somewere the thought is that if the status is either `Expired` or `Active` the enabled should be false so that it cannot be edtied all other statuses should be fine.

I have also tried to write it like this with brackets around the second statement

```
!((parseInt("@Model.Status") === @((int)Status.Expired))
```

and like this inverting the if but none of it solved it

```
 (parseInt("@Model.Status") !== @((int)Status.Expired)
```

Great comment by Pointy! but unfortunately it isn't the problem here either because even if I skip the whole && operator I still have the same problem with just

```
 !(parseInt("@Model.Status") === @((int)Status.Active) || !(parseInt("@Model.Status") === @((int)Status.Expired)))
```

this still gives the same problem

Comment: Understand that `&&` binds more tightly than `||`, as multiplication (`*`) binds more tightly than addition (`+`). You may therefore need parentheses around the whole `||` expression, with the `&&` outside that.

Comment: @Pointy great comment but even if I skip the whole && operator and only check the status it still the same result

Comment: Your condition is (as an overview) `!(a || !(b) && c)`, which can be re-written more clearly as `!(a ||  (!(b) && c))` as this is the execution you'd get. If `parseInt("@Model.Status") === @((int)Status.Active` returns `true` then neither `b` nor `c` nor their conjunction would be evaluated. If that first logical expression returns `false`, *then* would the others be evaluated but only their AND-ed value would be taken into account. Since I'm not sure what the logic is even supposed to check, I can't comment further. Can you say what you expect for which value of each expression?

Comment: @VLAZ What I want to check is that if the Model.Status is either Active or Expired then I want enabled to be true but if it is either Active or Expired I want enabled to be false. So if say Model.Status === InActive && Model.EditMode === "True" then enabled should be true

Comment: So, only one of the first two needs to be true **and** `Model.EditMode` should be `"True"` for `enabled` to be `true`, right? In all other instances (any other value of `@Model.Status` or `Model.EditMode` not `"True"`), it should be `false`

Comment: @VLAZ Well i think we think the same :) If either Model.Status === Active OR Expired enabled should always be false no matter what so Status always have to be something else for enabled to be true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition seems to be wrong.  `!(parseInt("@Model.Status") === @((int)Status.Active) || !(parseInt("@Model.Status") === @((int)Status.Expired)) && '@Model.EditMode' === 'True')`

can be viewed as `!(a || !(b) && c)` where

```
a = parseInt("@Model.Status") === @((int)Status.Active)
b = parseInt("@Model.Status") === @((int)Status.Expired)
c = '@Model.EditMode' === 'True'
```

The AND operator (`&&`) has higher precedence than `||`, so the actual evaluation order can be shown using grouping as `!(a || (!(b) && c))` the same way how `2 + 3 * 4` is evaluated as `2 + (3 * 4)`.

However, the logic presented does not match the requirement. The status should anything but Active or Expired *and* Edit Mode should be "True". However, it seems that the brackets are mismatched likely due to a typo, since the *entire* logical expression is negated, and further the second condition is also negated, whereas it shouldn't be.

The correct logical expression is `!(a || b) && c`. Substituting the logical tests:

```
!(parseInt("@Model.Status") === @((int)Status.Active) || parseInt("@Model.Status") === @((int)Status.Expired) &&
  '@Model.EditMode' === 'True'
```

I am not familiar with Kendo, but if it's possible to use `!==` then the expression can be simplified a bit by removing some of the brackets. According to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) `!(a || b)` is equivalent to `!a && !b`, so if we perform that substitution, we get `!a && !b && c`. If we also change from `!(parseInt("@Model.Status") === @((int)Status.Active))` to `parseInt("@Model.Status") !== @((int)Status.Active)` then we end up with:

```
parseInt("@Model.Status") !== @((int)Status.Active) && 
  parseInt("@Model.Status") !== @((int)Status.Expired) && 
  '@Model.EditMode' === 'True'
```

Comment: Thanks! this solved it perfectly. And a great explanation as well. Ended up going with the last example and it works perfectly! and so much more readable than before